# Android - PendingIntent not working

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver

Ok, to start off, I have been sitting here for 4 hours trying to solve this problem to no avail.

I'm using a PendingIntent to execute a broadcast but the PendingIntent just will not fire.

Here is the receiver declaration in my manifest:

`<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>`

In `AlarmReceiver.java`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "FIRED!");
}
```

In `AlarmService.java`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Service starting!");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
    try {
        pendingIntent.send();
    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "FAIL!", e);
    }
}
```

In my logcat, I am getting `Service starting!` but I'm not getting `FIRED!` or `FAIL!`. The code looks simple but it just won't work! Is there any reason why this code would not work?

P.S. Removing the `android:process` makes it work but I require the broadcast to be run in a separate process.

Comment: Try replacing `MainActivity.TAG` in `onReceive()`'s Log print with a String literal, or a field local to the Receiver class.

Comment: Try using AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pendingIntent); instead of pendingIntent.send();

Comment: @Mike M. Replaced with String literal, nothing happened :(

@ ResolutioN This was actually originally put in an alarm (so yeah, I tried this). I eventually got so frustrated, I just used pendingIntent.send() instead.

Comment: As said, it mentioned when the `android:process` attribute is removed, it works, so yes, I believe it is in the correct folder.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see your P.S. That's odd, 'cause I can't get it to not work. What Android version are you running under? Are you filtering your logcat by PID, by chance?

Comment: I guess I'll just remove the `android:process` attribute and start the broadcast in a new `Thread`, that's the closest I can get to a new process for now :(.

Comment: post your manifest please

Comment: Also, how are you starting your `Service`?